# When popping to a previous viewcontroller I get a duplicate of itself during the transition

Tags: iphone

I am using the following code to popping to a parent view controller (not always the direct parent in the stack), but for some reason I get the current view controller slide in over itself before the parent I am popping to.

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:vc animated:YES];
hasPopped = YES;
```

This appears to be down to the animation code Im using. The only reason I am setting this is because when the app is rotated to landscape the views come in from the bottom on the side. As raised in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102345/why-do-views-slide-out-at-the-bottom-when-landscape

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by turning the animated:off during the pop as the assigned animation was providing it